# Is it possible to hide code written in SAS EG

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have some project written in sas EG. It has its own promt variables and the result is some statement. I need to give this project to another people and I do not want them to see my code. Is it possible to hide it?
p.s. I can not use stored process function cause session works not in local machine. Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to hide the code?  Perhaps if you explain why there is a solution to the actual issue that doesn't involve hiding the code.

Comment: @Tom One reason I could think of would be because the source code contains ODBC credentials.  It's hard to believe it's 2016 and SAS still don't provide a nice way to secure ODBC credentials.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a stored compiled macro just like you could in base SAS.  I'm not sure if it would be included in the .egp file, though; you might have to distribute the macro file separately, in which case you should use the option to use relative paths.

Comment: my session is on the server, so I could create stored process only on the server, besides as I remember, everyone can select "Show stored processs code"

Comment: The source code of compiled macros can only be viewed when you compile using the `SOURCE` option. So your code will be save in a pre- compiled macro. You can even encrypt it using the `STORE SECURE` option.

Comment: @bobby1232 Stored Compiled Macros are not stored processes - entirely different thing.  EG should be able to handle SCMs regardless of where you're running your code.